# Gradlewrapper in muti projects download gradle again and again behavor

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have APP1, APP2 android projects, using gradlewrapper to build it; and every project have a gradlewrapper and folder.

```
ROOTPATH
build_all.sh

APP1
    ├── gradle
    │   └── wrapper
    │       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
    │       └── gradle-wrapper.properties

    APP2
    ├── gradle
    │   └── wrapper
    │       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
    │       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
```

When build all, APP1 downloaded gradle-2.10 once, APP2 downloaded gradle-2.10 too, This is werid in one build environment. I want to download gradle-2.10 once when build all apps if I config the same gradle version in gradle-wrapper.properties.

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=http://localhost/builds/tools/gradle/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

Any one know how to handle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I saw this happen once in my projects when the `gradle-wrapper.jar` was not the same. Please make sure, you use the same version of the wrapper jar in all projects.

Comment: I compared gradle-wrapper.jar in beyoncompare, they are the same.